# CSS - restricting the container to the height of the browser window (viewable area)

Tags: css, height

All,

I am writing the CSS for our web application. The whole application needs to fit in the browser window without any scrollbars appearing. I also want to set a min-height & min-width properties so that if the browser window gets smaller than our min., only then will the scroll bars appear.

Is there a way of achieving this in CSS please?

Comment: Isn't this what happens by default? You specify a height/width (or that gets decided by the size of the content), and scrollbars appear if the window is smaller?

Comment: yes it does but it depends on the min. resolution you have catered for right?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem depends to the screen size of the viewers, which may varies greatly. My propose is that you should create a fix width/height div which is the wrapper of all the content (usually [1024x768](http://designsadvice.com/forums/topic/standard-web-dimensions)).

Comment: thats the problem I have. Also different people have different preferances, like bookmark bars visible which takes up viewport space as well...